# Can a Voip push cert and APN push cert be concatenated into a single cert for use with either regular push or Voip push?

Tags: ios, ssl, https, apple-push-notifications

I've got an app in the app store which is using silent push notifications, a new version is going to use Voip push instead.

Previously I have been able to concatenate a dev push cert and a prod push cert and then use that combined cert in the server code that sends the push. The advantage of this is the server code does not need to change certificates if it sending the push over the production environment or the sandbox environment - when the connection is made the relevant cert within the concatenated is automatically used.

A production push certificate and sandbox push certificate are different, and production push token and dev push token are different. Yet the method of combining the prod and dev cert into one worked. So in theory it should also work for a voip push cert and a non-voip cert assuming they have the same passwords and were generated using the game CSR.
I would like to do a similar thing with silent push certificate and the voip push certificate so that the server can use the same certificate and therefore the server will be compatible with both old versions of the app and new ones without having to do something like identify the version of the app and change certificates.

I've been doing a few experiments but not been able to get this to work so far.
Has anybody done anything similar, or how what steps to perform to concatenate the two.

Comment: I'm experimenting with this, doesn't look like its possible. I think its possible to concat the dev and prod certs as they probably have the same key, but looks like the voip key is different even if all the certificates are generated using the same certificate signing request. Hmm, you'd think as the CSR is the same the keys should be the same though too?

Answer (score 0):

We can not use same certificate and device token for both simple push and VOIP Push. You must need to create separate certificates for both. Because both generates different device token which can't be used for one another.

Comment: Thank you but you did not understand my question. I know different tokens are needed, and I know different certificates are needed. Please re-read the question more carefully, if its not clear what I'm asking my apologies. I have added an additional paragraph.